# Integrate Rundeck with SSO (Okta)

Tags: single-sign-on, okta, rundeck

Rundeck community has challenges managing users/roles. We have Okta for one-stop shop of authenticating applications to users.

Is there a way to easily manage this with SSO? Preferably Okta.

Please suggest any other ways if applicable.

TIA.

Comment: SSO is only supported by Process Automation (formerly "Rundeck Enterprise") take a look: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/sso.html

Comment: Is there a better way to manage authentication in Rundeck community?

Comment: LDAP / LDAPS / AD authentication: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/learning/getting-started/users-overview.html#ldap-active-directory-integration